# MySQL multiple update sets in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I update multiple rows in MySQL using one query? It has been asked before, I know, but I have no idea how to use the CASE expressions.

I currently have this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . $DBtable . " SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id= :id";  
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

How can I add a timestamp in the same query:

```
// Add timestamp
$date = new DateTime();
$now = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
"UPDATE " . $DBtable . " SET dl_time = ". $now . " WHERE id= :id";
```

`dl_time` is the name of the column.

Comment: . . "multiple update sets" isn't really what you want.  You simply want to update multiple columns in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple columns in an `update`:

```
UPDATE " . $DBtable . "
    SET clicks = clicks + 1,
        dl_time = now()
    WHERE id= :id;
```

Note that there is one `set` clause, with the assignments separated by commas.

Note that this version uses the *database* time rather than the *application* time.  Unless you specifically want the application time, the database time makes the rows more consistent.

Comment: surely that will just update one row - unless multiple rows share the same id? Or was the question `"how to update multiple columns in one query?"`

Comment: @RamRaider . . . The OP appears to be a programmer with limited knowledge of SQL and database terminology.  If you look into the question, it says "How can I add a timestamp in the same query:".